# How can I change the value of the last row of a dataframe if some conditions for that last row is satisfied?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working with the following pandas dataframe:

```
issue_status   market_phase    state
    10              0          OPEN 
    40              0          INTRA 
    30              0          SCHEDULE 
    20              0          TEMP
    40              0          NULL
```

I would like to write some python code so that when the `issue_status == 40` and `market_phase == 0` for the **LAST ROW**, then map the `state` of the **LAST ROW** to `CLOSED`.

I have the following code that doesn't quite work:

```
df.loc[(df.iloc[-1]['issue_status'] == 40) &
(df.iloc[-1]['market_phase'] == 0),df.iloc[-1]['market_state']] = 'CLOSED'
```

So in the above example the output would be:

```
    issue_status   market_phase    state
        10              0          OPEN 
        40              0          INTRA 
        30              0          SCHEDULE 
        20              0          TEMP
        40              0          CLOSED
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple if statement along with changes on iloc can be used.

**Code:**

```
if (in_df.iloc[-1]['issue_status'] == 40) and (in_df.iloc[-1]['market_phase'] == 0):
    print("Yes")
    in_df['state'].iloc[-1] = "CLOSED"
```

**Output:**

```
issue_status  market_phase    state
        10             0     OPEN
        40             0    INTRA
        30             0 SCHEDULE
        20             0     TEMP
        40             0   CLOSED
```